# Using just Past Simple in the Third conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

> Genderson: I told you not to take the turnpike.
>
> KRAMER: I thought we would blend in.
>
> Genderson: If we **took** the Palisades, this never **would've happened**.
>
> KRAMER: Then we would've had all that bridge traffic.
>
> Genderson: Ah, just drive.

I don't like **took** in the conditional sentence. Instead of **took** it should be **had taken**. What is it: a different grammar structure or just a colloquialism?

Comment: It's just colloquial sloppiness.

Comment: Colloquialism. The dialogue in Seinfeld is one big exercise in how to talk like a New Yorker.

Comment: It doesn't feel sloppy to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as StoneyB and relaxing said in their comments. Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage* also mentions this "past simple instead of a past perfect". Here is the relevant section.

> **262 if (7): other structures found in spoken English**
>   
>   **4 mixed tenses**
>   Sometimes a simple past tense is used with *if* where a past perfect would be normal. This is more common in American English.
>       ***If I knew*** you were coming I'd have baked a cake.
>       ***If I had*** the money with me I would have bought you one.
>       ***If I didn't have*** my walking boots on I think I would have really hurt my foot.