# Third conditional with modals in both sentences - can it look the same?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

2nd conditional:

> I would leave if I could.

3rd conditional:

> I would have left if I could  --the same form of "could"

but

> I would have left if I could have used the car.

Is that correct? Is the first example of 3rd conditional correct, i.e. using the same form of the modal as the second conditional?

Comment: Using the _past simple_ tense instead of the _past perfect_ in the 3rd conditional is acceptable in **colloquial** English where the grammar is usually mixed up. [See here on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18318/using-just-past-simple-in-the-third-conditional) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60758/the-third-conditional-for-if-i-could) for the "could" issue.

Comment: @TasneemZh Then how would you say the second sentence -__I would have left if I could have   ?__

Comment: Change it to **I would have left if I _had been able to_**.

Answer (score -1):

2nd conditional sentence is structured like this:

If + Subject + Verb(past), Subject + would + V(inf)

**3rd conditional sentence is structured like this:**

If + Subject + had + past participle, Subject + would/could/might + have + past participle

So look at your question, the sentence you are confused is **grammatically correct with 3rd conditional sentence's structure.**